# How to solve this problem on overlapping?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, combinatorics, explanation

In cases of problems involving order and ranking where there are two indices (namely left and right) there is a particular chance of overlapping. Let us take an example to justify this:

> Ranjan is 16th from the left end and Vineet is 10th from the right end in a row of boys. If there are eight boys between Ranjan and Vineet, how many boys are there in the row?

Now my instructor told me about the concept of maximum overlapping limit. Wherein he told me to take Smallest index(S) out of the given two indices and calculate the maximum overlapping limit by the formula S-2.

I am unable to understand what he exactly means and where this formula is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

He probably means the following:

> ```
>      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
>
>      x  x  x  x  x  x  V  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  R
>                      S=10 |<---   S-2 = 8  --->|  1
>     16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
> ```

> Once the smaller of the two indices is fixed the largest possible overlap is obtained if the other boy is at the end of the line. It should be clear from the figure that that leaves room for exactly S-2 boys.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer but why is it the maximum overlapping limit?

Comment: Can you describe slightly more?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible arrangements for the room:

```
      ------ - -------- -
(16 - 8 - 2) V    8     R (10 - 8 - 2) - overlap (16 kids total)

--------------- - -------- - ---------
             15 R    8     V 9         - no overlap (34 kids total)
```

Finding the maximum overlapping limit helps to provide more information about the possible correct arrangement. The "maximum overlapping limit" here *happens to be* `8`, and I'm sure the coincidence that there are 8 people between them confuses the issue.

Let's say instead that V is 12 away from the edge. The minimum of V(12) and R(16) is 12, minus two (counting both V and R) leaves a maximum number of people between them as 10. Conversely, if we were to say that V is 5 away from the edge, the minimum of V(5) and R(16) is 5, minus two (counting both V and R again) is only 3. With a maximum overlap of only 3, we can deduce that the stated 8 between them *must* be not overlapping.

In summary, the formula for "maximum overlapping limit" is `MOL = S - 2` because it's the smaller of the two numbers subtract the two kids (who themselves do not count in the overlap); this pushes one of the kids right up against the wall, thereby making it maximal.